# Reuse DTOs on both client and server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have a library of DTOs in a project that I'm referencing in both the web site providing the SOAP APIs that use them and the client that consumes them. The use-case for reusing these objects is that several of them contain helper methods and properties that make their use easier.

The thing is, when I expose my APIs on the server side, a wsdl file is automatically generated. In the client application, I add a web reference as per usual and visual studio then generates *an entirely new set of DTOs* in a new namespace. This is normally great when you don't have access to the underlying server code but in this case I do. At the moment I'm using a fairly complicated method using reflection and type checking to convert the auto-generated classes to my own custom objects and vice versa.

My question is this: is there a way to get visual studio to use the objects in my library instead of auto-generating its own from the wsdl?

Comment: Is there any good reason for avoiding WCF? With WCF you won't have this problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I know absolutely nothing about WCF apart from what it stands for :-) Can you give an example of how this would bypass the issue?

Comment: With WCF you don't need to generate any code at all. You just define the service's interface and use it at both ends (server and client). Google for a WCF tutorial, it's worth the extra effort.

Comment: I will, thank  you! Not knowing anything about it, I didn't think to look. I'm curious though, how does this address the requirement of extending functionality on the DTOs? Some properties iterate over information etc. Can this be dealt with or extended using WCF?